# Minify dependencies in AngularJS provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have the following provider in my app.js main file:

```
.provider('securityInterceptor', function() {
        this.$get = function($location, $q) {
            return function(promise) {
                return promise.then(null, function(response) {
                    if(response.status === 403 || response.status === 401) {
                        $location.path('/unauthorized');
                    }
                    return $q.reject(response);
                });
            };
        };
    })
```

But there seems to be a problem when minifying this. I found out that it's because of $location and $q. How can I safely inject those in the function? Using something like the following doesn't help (actually it's not applicable):

```
this.$get = function(['$location', '$q'], $location, $q) { 
   ...
}
```

or

```
.provider('securityInterceptor', ['$location', '$q', function ($location, $q)... ]
```

How can I safely inject these dependencies? I'm using ASP .NET MVC's BundleConfig.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this variant:

```
this.$get = ['$location', '$q', function($location, $q) {
    ...
}];
```

See more info here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. I guess it was the only combination I didn't try. :)